# Tensorflow (protobuf ?) import error: unexpected keyword argument "syntax"

Tags: python, import, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

Whenever I try to import tensorflow I get this error

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/graph_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/node_def_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/attr_value_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import tensor_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_tensor__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_pb2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework import resource_handle_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_resource__handle__pb2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle_pb2.py", line 22, in <module>
    serialized_pb=_b('\n/tensorflow/core/framework/resource_handle.proto\x12\ntensorflow\"m\n\x0eResourceHandle\x12\x0e\n\x06\x64\x65vice\x18\x01 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\tcontainer\x18\x02 \x01(\t\x12\x0c\n\x04name\x18\x03 \x01(\t\x12\x11\n\thash_code\x18\x04 \x01(\x04\x12\x17\n\x0fmaybe_type_name\x18\x05 \x01(\tB4\n\x18org.tensorflow.frameworkB\x13ResourceHandleProtoP\x01\xf8\x01\x01\x62\x06proto3')
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'syntax'
```

I suspected it was a protobuf error - but I've tried uninstalling both tensorflow and protobuf and reinstalling them with different protobuf versions but to no avail. Really kind of lost on this one-  any help is appreciated a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by uninstalling `python-protobuf` with apt-get remove and uninstalling protobuf with pip, and then installing tensorflow with pip.

Answer (score 0):

The `syntax` keyword is introduced in proto3 (and backported into proto2 in proto3-era parsers, so `syntax = "proto2";` is valid).

So either:

- update the parser tools (possibly `protoc`)
- make sure you use pre-proto3 syntax only, so: no `syntax`, `map`, etc